# Formatting XSLT document to display multiple nicknames on a single line

Tags: html, xml, xslt

My xml documents contain a list of people, and these people can have 0 or more nicknames. I am having trouble trying to display all the nicknames properly in my xslt document.

I can have all the nicknames listed by using:

```
<xsl:for-each select="name/nickname">

    Nickname: <xsl:value-of select="." />

</xsl:for-each>
```

The output of this is something like:

```
Nickname: nickname1
Nickname: nickname2
```

Which is a problem as I would like to get an output without Nickname: being listed so many times, i.e.

```
Nickname: nickname1, nickname2.
```

What I currently have is:

```
<p>
    Nickname: 

    <xsl:for-each select="name/nickname">

        <xsl:value-of select="." />, 

    </xsl:for-each>
</p>
```

Problems with this are:

1. Nickname will always be printed at least once even if a nickname doesn't exist.
2. There will always be a left over comma (,).

I am hoping there are suggestions to get around these two issues, I tried to use != "" but I'm not sure if this is allowed if an person doesn't contain a nickname.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or,

```
<xsl:for-each select="name/nickname">
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">Nickname: </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">, </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="name[nickname]">
     <xsl:text>&#xA;Nicknames: </xsl:text>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="nickname"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="nickname">
  <xsl:if test="not(position() = 1)">
    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>
 <person>
  <name trueName="John">
    <nickname>X1</nickname>
    <nickname>X2</nickname>
    <nickname>X3</nickname>
  </name>
 </person>
 <person>
  <name trueName="Peter">
    <nickname>Y1</nickname>
    <nickname>Y2</nickname>
    <nickname>Y3</nickname>
  </name>
 </person>
 </t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
Nicknames: X1, X2, X3
Nicknames: Y1, Y2, Y3
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that (untested):

```
<xsl:when test="name/nickname">
 Nickname:
 <xsl:for-each select="name/nickname">
   <xsl:value-of select="." />
   <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::nickname)">,</xsl:if> 
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:when>
```

Answer (score 0):

Input :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
  <nickname>1</nickname>
  <nickname>2</nickname>
  <nickname>3</nickname>
</test>
```

Transform :

```
<xsl:template match='/'>
    <xsl:if test='count(//nickname) > 0'>
      <result>
      <xsl:for-each select='//nickname'>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test='position() = 1'>
            Nickname : <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">,</xsl:if>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">,</xsl:if>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </result>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

Output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>Nickname : 1,2,3</result>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in XSLT 2.0:

Input :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
  <nickname>1</nickname>
  <nickname>2</nickname>
  <nickname>3</nickname>
</test>
```

Transform :

```
<xsl:template match='/'>
Nickname: <xsl:value-of select="/test/nickname" separator=", "/>
</xsl:template>
```